# How should I connect to an existing threaded ABS sink trap fitting?

Tags: plumbing

[image]

My wife got rid of the old sink and trap that was attached. Didn’t honk much of it, but as a novice, when I got under to attach a j trap, realized I had no idea how to connect to the pipe from the wall due to the connection.  Are there connectors that connect male/male?  Is that even what I need?

Answer (score 1):

It looks pretty standard.  You'll need (obviously) the right set of pipes to construct a J trap that reaches from your wall pipes to the bottom of the sink. A kit might be available in your hardware store.  Measure the pipe diameter (likely 1.25 inches in the US ) to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

Often the manufacturers of that type of trap use a proprietary thread at the union, making it difficult to mate another "1/2 of a trap" (the J shaped part) if it is not the same make.

You *may* be able to buy a complete trap and use just the J shaped bend to mate with the existing part that is glued on to your waste piping, then cobble together various tubes to reach the waste tailpiece from your sink.

More likely you will need to cut off the "half trap" that remains and use a modern adjustable P-Trap (which will actually probably make it easier to align and connect in the end).

[image]

[image]